# Expectation of the minimum of two continuous random variables - using the joint pdf

Tags: probability, expected-value

Define $Z = \min(X, Y)$ and the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ as $f_{XY}(x,y)$.

I saw an approach that said

$$
E[Z] = \int \int \min(x,y) f_{XY}(x,y) \,dy\,dx
$$

Is this readily obvious, or do you need to convert the following:
$$
E[Z] = \int \min(x,y)f_Z(z) \,dz
$$

to the above?

Comment: Obvious. For any function $g(x,y)$, the expected value of $g$ is $\int \int g f_{XY}dxdy$$.

Comment: @YJT Is this the law of unconscious statistician? If so, I've only seen that for the one variable case, but it seems it applies to any number of variables?

Comment: @David Yes.  Consider the (generically 2-to-1) change of variables $(Z,W)=(\min(X,Y),\max(X,Y))$.

Comment: Yes.it applies to more than one variable.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do that. In general you have
$$
\operatorname E(g(W)) = \int_{\mathcal W} u\cdot f_{g(W)}(u)\, du = \int_{\mathcal X} g(x)f_W(x)\, dx.
$$
Using the second integral is often simpler because you are given $f_W$ and there is no need to find $f_{g(W)}.$

Some people call this the "law of the unconscious statistician," and if you google that term you will find it.

Answer (score 0):

The two definitions are the same, but I think that in a real problem you have to use the second one....

For example, let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. rv's following a $Exp(1)$ distribution.

to find

$$E(Z)=\int_0^{\infty}2t e^{-2t}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}w e^{-w}dw=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: This is quite incorrect. There is not in fact a need to find the density function of $Z. \qquad$